# dynamic parameter passing to execlp() function in C

Tags: c, variables, parameters

To make things simple, I have modified my program. What I want to do is accept any number of parameters during runtime and pass it to `execlp()`. I am using fixed length 2d array `m[][]` such that any unused (remaining) slots maybe passed as `NULL` to `execlp` (in this case `m[2][]`).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char m[3][5], name[25];
    int i;
    strcpy(name, "ls");
    strcpy(m[0], "-t");
    strcpy(m[1], "-l");
    //To make a string appear as NULL (not just as an empty string)
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        m[2][i] = '\0'; // or m[2][i] = 0 (I've tried both)
    execlp(name, m[0], m[1], m[2], '\0', 0, NULL);  
    // Does not execute because m[2] is not recognized as NULL
    return 0;
    }
```

How do i do it?

Comment: It seems you ar forgetting to pass argv[0]. You should use `execlp(name, name, m[0], m[1], m[2], '\0', 0, NULL);`

Comment: You have three zeroes at the end of the argument list; one is sufficient.  You probably should use `(char *)0` or `(char *)NULL` since the last argument is supposed to be a null `char` pointer, though you can probably get away with just `NULL`.  On a 64-bit machine, the `'\0'` is an `int` and not as big as a pointer; ditto the `0`.  What you really seem to be looking for, though, is [`execvp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to accept any number of arguments, what you should aim to use is [`execvp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) instead of `execlp()`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *argv[] = { "ls", "-l", "-t", 0 };
    execvp(argv[0], argv);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execvp() '%s' (%d: %s)\n", argv[0], errno,
            strerror(errno));
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The `execvp()` function takes an arbitrary length list of arguments in the form of the array, unlike `execlp()` where any single call that you write takes only a fixed length list of arguments.  If you want to accommodate 2, 3, 4, ... arguments, you should write separate calls for each different number of arguments.  Anything else is not wholly reliable.

Comment: I want to keep calling the execvp in a while loop like a shell, until a 'quit' is entered. In this case how do I change the arguments in argv[]..?

Comment: That depends on how your shell is parsing the arguments.  Basically, I'd expect your shell to be creating the argument list as it parses the command line, and therefore, it will have an `argv` available to your shell, which you'll then use as shown: (`execvp(argv[0], argv)`) or something very similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *args[] = {"ls", "-t", "-l" };
    execlp(args[0], args[0], args[1], args[2], NULL);
    perror( "execlp()" );
    return 0;
    }
```

For simplicity I replaced all the string management stuff by a fixed pointer array. There is only one final NULL argument needed for execlp(), execle() would also need the environment pointer *after* the NULL arg.

Answer (score 0):

```
 char m[3][5];
```

This is a 2D array of characters.

```
m[2] is a element of the 2D array that is it it a 1D Array of characters.
```

So it always having a constant address.And it never be NULL as it is a constant address which can not be NULL.Again it can not be assigned to NULL so you have to use NULL as last parameter.

execlp() use NULL as terminating argument so you have bound to mention it.

If you use command line argument then last command line argument is always NULL.SO last element of  char *argv[]   argument can be used as terminating argument in execlp() function.