# Dynamic execlp in C

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to pass a dynamic value to execlp and it does not work.

```
execlp("./mb", "./mb", mbtorun, (char *)0);
```

`mbtorun` is an integral value that is dynamic
So, I google'd one of the first results I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818491/dynamic-parameter-passing-to-execlp-function-in-c):

But, the value there is not dynamic.. Can you please suggest me any ideas?

In python for example I could do this

```
cmd = "./mb" + mbtorun
os.system(cmd)
```

Obviously `os.system` is not the best, but that's just one of the ways..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All arguments must be *strings*, so you must convert the integer value to a string.

There is no nice shortcut standard function for that, so you have to use e.g. `snprintf` for it.

Comment: `char stringNum[20];`
`sprintf(stringNum,"%d",mbtorun);`
`execlp("./mb", "./mb", "stringNum", (char *)0);`

Makes sense now?

Comment: @user2015933 Almost, except you're now passing the literal string `"stringNum"` as argument. Loose the quotes in the `execlp` call.

Comment: Is there a reason why execlp accepts only strings?. Just a question of interest.

Comment: @user2015933 Remember that the arguments are passed, as-is, into the new programs `argv` array.